# How to sum columns together in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to solve sums up with the column, such as after sums up the column which i want and show the result.

I have made a sql script like this:

```
Select sum(TotalPrice), sum(PaymentType)
from tblTransaction
where Name = 'John'
```

But I have many People in the database and some are the same person and i want put all the price and payment type together for same person

SQL Table Data:

```
Name      TotalPrice          Payment Type

John      1000                      1
Karen     2000                      2
John      3000                      1
```

Payment Type will add up to 2 not 1

Comment: Add `GROUP BY Name` at the end of the query.. By the way, SUMming a type doesn't make sense to me. If someone has a payment of Type 1 and one of type 2, they did not make 1 purchase of type 3 ;)

Comment: @SchmitzIT, This is SO, everything goes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you use `GROUP By`

```
Select Name,sum(TotalPrice), PaymentType
from tblTransaction 
where Name = 'John'
GROUP BY Name,PaymentType
```